# How to get information about the file

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

I am able to open and stream the file no issue by using the following, however I need to be able to use the file information that is stored inside the bucket.

```
 const db = connection.connections[0].db
          const bucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(db, {
            bucketName: bucketName
          });
          bucket.openDownloadStreamByName(filename).pipe(res)
```

For example I would like to be able to set the following

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', (TYPE)),
res.setHeader('Content-Length', (LENGTH)),
```

I am wondering the following above allows `options` however I don't know if the pipe stops us from setting the content-type and length after it starts piping.

Comment: according to docs, no you can't get stream info about file info but in source code seems you can. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/be34a94651c2b18df303f248e10b1bfa06dc445e/src/gridfs/download.ts#L126) and [this](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/be34a94651c2b18df303f248e10b1bfa06dc445e/src/gridfs/download.ts#L49) . so you could get `contentType` using `bucket.openDownloadStreamByName(...).s.files[0].contentType` or `bucket.openDownloadStreamByName(...).s.file?.contentType`

Comment: @bogdanoff thanks - could you put this as an answer and I'll tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs, no you can't get file info from stream but in source code seems you can.

According to [this](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/be34a94651c2b18df303f248e10b1bfa06dc445e/src/gridfs/download.ts#L126) and [this](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/be34a94651c2b18df303f248e10b1bfa06dc445e/src/gridfs/download.ts#L49), you could get `contentType` by accessing

```
bucket.openDownloadStreamByName(...).s.files[0].contentType
```

or

```
bucket.openDownloadStreamByName(...).s.file?.contentType
```